# How to loop tables with associations ROR5 has_many and belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Ah Have a two models

`Accounts` , & `trades`

Trades belongs_to accounts, how do i  find and loop through tables on `index` in my controller  just like  Devise uses

```
def index
    @trades = Trade.where(user_id: current_user).order("created_at DESC")
  end
```

how can i achieve the above with trades & accounts  instead of trade & User  remeber trades belongs to accounts just like trades belonged to users

ok so someone said ah could do this
would it work..?

```
 Accounts>ApplicationController
 def index
   @trades = Trade.where(account_id: current_account).order("created_at DESC")
  end 
private 
def current_account
  Account.find_by_param(param).id
end

end
```

Comment: I know this is not the solution but a suggestion:
When you have the right account and your account model has the `has_many :trades` you can reduce your code with the next `current_account.trades.order('created_at DESC')`

Answer (score 0):

You can define a private method like below in your controller

```
private 
def current_account
  Account.find_by_param(param).id
end
```

Then you can use the current_account method in your query

```
@trades = Trade.where(account_id: current_account).order("created_at DESC")
```

Comment: wow.. ok lemme test this... would this function as a helper..? like am in accounts index  can ah  do

Comment: `
Accounts>ApplicationController
 def index
   @trades = Trade.where(account_id: current_account).order("created_at DESC")
  end 
private 
def current_account
  Account.find_by_param(param).id
end

end  
`